# Many navbar buttons stretch the screen instead of wrapping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My application uses navbar buttons which are generated at runtime, and sometimes there are so many they cause the line of buttons to stretch outside the screen instead of wrapping onto the next line. This used to wrap OK in bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha but no longer in v4.1.3. Is there a way to get the buttons to wrap onto the next line instead of overflowing to the right and generating a scroll bar?

Here is some sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Many navbar buttons</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<h1>Many navbar buttons</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand"></span>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#navbarSelect" aria-controls="navbarSelect" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSelect">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button1" title="button1" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button2" title="button2" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button3" title="button3" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button4" title="button4" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button5" title="button5" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button6" title="button6" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button7" title="button7" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button8" title="button8" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button9" title="button9" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button10" title="button10" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button11" title="button11" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button12" title="button12" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button13" title="button13" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button14" title="button14" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button15" title="button15" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button16" title="button16" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button17" title="button17" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button18" title="button18" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button19" title="button19" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button20" title="button20" value="Button Text">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.navbar-nav` css class.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Many navbar buttons</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<h1>Many navbar buttons</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand"></span>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#navbarSelect" aria-controls="navbarSelect" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSelect">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button1" title="button1" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button2" title="button2" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button3" title="button3" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button4" title="button4" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button5" title="button5" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button6" title="button6" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button7" title="button7" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button8" title="button8" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button9" title="button9" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button10" title="button10" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button11" title="button11" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button12" title="button12" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button13" title="button13" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button14" title="button14" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button15" title="button15" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button16" title="button16" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button17" title="button17" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button18" title="button18" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button19" title="button19" value="Button Text">
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input class="nav-link btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button20" title="button20" value="Button Text">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```